# rewrite url address using vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, url-rewriting

just like the title is. When users land on the second page, after clicking submit on first page, i want the second page to read the url, then modify the aspx page in the end and send the user to a specific page.
e.g -
www.abc.com/page1.aspx --> click submit --> redirect to www.abc.com/page2.aspx
the code should read "/page2.aspx" and then rewrite it as "/page5.aspx" and automatically redirect to page5.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You sound like you want to build a multi-step wizard. There is a control in asp.net for this, the `<asp:Wizard />` control.

This is gives you multiple steps that you can move backwards and forwards through but the best thing is that it remembers the data for each of the steps. So when you are on the last step you can go back and pull the data out of all the steps and process it. You can also make decisions based on data in the current step to decide which step you move to next.

- [basic overview at msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs0za4w6.aspx)
- [more introductions on scott gu's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/02/21/438732.aspx)
- [an article I wrote that will help you hop between steps in a clean way](http://runtingsproper.blogspot.com/2009/09/better-way-to-reference-your-wizard.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
Response.Redirect("~/page5.aspx")
```